# Is this a good way to allow multiple users to access a database at the same time?

Tags: java, database, locking, h2

I have asked questions regarding this, but this is a bit different.

Right now, I have my program set up to insert a query (whether it is to read from or write to the database), commit the changes, and immediately close the connection. This allows for the database to be locked for a very short amount of time. I am using H2 for my database, and I have "AUTO_SERVER=TRUE" set, so that the database can run over the network and allow multiple connections simultaneously.

Now, here is my dilemma. If, for some reason, a user attempts to access the database at the exact time that the lock file is present, how should I handle it? Should I display a JOptionPane that notifies them that the database is currently locked by another user, and that they should ensure that all other connections are closed and try again? If so, what Java code would I use to determine whether or not the lock file exists (or, simply if the database IS indeed locked)?

As usual. thank you in advance for any helpful responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The H2 daemon thread is creating the lock to avoid having another daemon thread come in and try to operate on the database file while it is currently in use. If you are using Auto Server mode then the H2 daemon thread will check for the existence of a lock and if it is there it will try to connect to the server specified in the lock file.

If two users try to connect to the same database, the first will gain the lock and start the H2 server, the second will connect to the server that the first one has started.

Check out the documentation on [auto mixed mode](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#auto_mixed_mode)

Comment: Will this work if access to the database is over the network via shared folders?

Comment: Maybe, If the two machines can't communicate with each other over the port specified in the lock file then it will fail. It's possible that both machines have access to the same share, but cannot communicate directly to each other.

Comment: See, I found it (so far) to work best with a couple of lines of code that commit the changes and then close the connection. Is that efficient?

Comment: It may be, depending on use case. Starting and stopping the server has some overhead involved, but that may be out weighted by the overhead involved in having the server continually running.

Comment: I think that's a much better option then, the way I have it. So, let's say someone tries to do something on one computer while another computer has the database locked. How would I go about determining if the database is locked? (Ex: If lock file exists, then notify the user that it is locked.)

Comment: You don't have to, thats the magic of auto server and the lock file that H2 creates. the H2 daemon thread determines if the database is in use, if it is in use then the daemon simply connects to the already running server. I would strongly recommend reading the H2 documentation and tutorial to determine the proper application of H2 for your needs: http://h2database.com/html/tutorial.html

Comment: But, I used the auto server, and that alone didn't seem to work. The second computer that I was using was unable to retrieve information from the database.

Comment: Okay, I retract my previous statement. I just removed the commit and close connection lines of code, and it still worked, just with the auto server on. So, do I still need to use the commit statement? What is the benefit of using "commit", or the risk of not using it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe i'm wrong but if your H2 base is in server mode you don't have any lock and can connect multiple user at the same time (you must configure your datasource for server mode and not embedded mode).

Comment: I had it set up with "AUTO_SERVER=TRUE", and it created a lock file when I started adding to the database. I then had to add a line of code to commit the changes, and another to close the connection, in order to delete the lock file.

Comment: Did you use this connection string syntax? jdbc:h2:tcp://<server>[:<port>]/[<path>]<database>